# create eventHandler for contextmenu on specific element in canvas with paperjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

I've created a canvas with some [path](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/) elements, using `paperjs`.
for each element, I would like to implement eventHandler for `contextmenu`. `paperjs` [support mouse events](http://paperjs.org/reference/mouseevent/) but does not support `onContextMenu`.

this is how I can add `onClick` event handler:

```
function addOnClick(clickArea) {
  //clickArea is path object
  clickArea.onClick = (e) => {console.log("my on click handler!"}
}
```

how can I add `onContextMenu` ?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, this is not a built-in feature of Paper.js but you can workaround this by taking adventage of the undocumented `MouseEvent.event` property. This is actually the original event catched by Paper.js so you can use it to detect which mouse button was pressed and adapt your logic accordingly.
Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.4/S/fVGxbsIwEP2Vk5ckEopYWIJgaNYOFYzQwTiXxIp7VzkODCj/XjuGILXQk2zr7t6992xfBckvFIXYd+hUKxZCcRVyxdQ7UNoqg7ABwgt8SNfm5VRJr0d7JPChkBzaAs4aL3lMFveelZUe+gJWy7lUa2NKNuwnEraSGkxCa8zW4QgrSuZMpdGq89Ipnj1tBpstzKq6vpXzuJ8G55hgC8vsAQrBtNNN696m/sSYRqnQHAFNj78H3rF+hZ+szk7rgZTTXvbJzIM0PCT7Cxlu0sR4HNzMqoDEKon84xPWv9Zf0NoA/IfXf+vJouy+WZPrRXH4HH8A) demonstrating the workaround.

```js
const circle = new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 50,
    fillColor: 'orange'
});

circle.onClick = (event) => {
    if (event.event.button > 0) {
        onRightButtonClick();
    } else {
        onLeftButtonClick();
    }
};

function onLeftButtonClick() {
    console.log('left button clicked');
}

function onRightButtonClick() {
    console.log('right button clicked');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My problem with this is that I will have to right-click 2 times to trigger my function. In addition, I still get the default context menu. I can try to "catch" the default behavior - will it interfere with the solution?