# Paperjs how to prevent multiple buttons canceling a drag event on mouseup / allow paperjs only use left button

Tags: javascript, paperjs

If you:

- **mousedown left button ↓**
- **mousedown right button ↓**
- **mouseup right button ↑**

The drag event gets canceled by **mouseup right button** , I don't want that to happen. 
 *(only want that to happen on **mouseup left button** , because the event was started by **mlb**.)*

- I've tried `preventDefault(), stopPropagation()` on both paper and
  window event.
- I've tried emitting mousedown/mousedrag on mouseup `tool.emit("mousedown", tool.onMouseDown);` not sure if I'm doing something wrong with it, but it runs the mousedown function once and stops, and I don't think it keeps event data from the first mousedown.

Is there any way to prevent this, maybe even preventing Paperjs from accessing the right button entirely if needed?

I know this has been kind and issue for a while now: https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/1355 
yet there is a fix for accessing 1,2,3.. buttons `(event as any).event.button`, 
 there is no fix for preventing the dragging to be set to `false`.

P.S Appreciate for any help!

Comment: I'm afraid that this requires a change in paper.js source code. Otherwise, an hacky solution could be to patch the event listener API to be able to control filter which events are forwarded to paper.js or not (as you mention).

Comment: This answer should help you out https://stackoverflow.com/a/61572337/4825796